# Magento : Find a layout handle for product category page?

Tags: magento

I know : we can update a layout of a view in magento by using its layout handle for example "http://domain.com/shops/index.php/customer/account/index/" it has a layout handle like    by using this in local.xml we can update layout of that particular view like removing the cart sidebar as follows

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
   <customer_account_index>
    <remove name="cart_sidebar"/>
  </customer_account_index>
</layout>
```

And what i want to know is, i created a menu items fall like men->Tshirts and it goes to the url like "http://domain.com/shops/index.php/men/t-shirts.html", how can i remove the cart sidebar from this page?

Comment: so you want a handle for a specific category? or all categories?

Comment: Want handle for all categories, including sub sub category if possible, like men->Tshirts->graphic shirt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the general layout for categories `catalog_category_view`, but Magento also loads a specific layout handle for a category `<CATEGORY_{ID_HERE}>` so you ca use for example `<CATEGORY_5>` You can also specify a custom layout code in the category edit page under the design tab. You can also set it's children to inherit this by editing them.

Answer (score 4):

On category page the handles Magento fires (in order) are

1. The full action name handler `catalog_category_view`
2. A special `catalog_category_layered` handler
3. A special `CATEGORY_[ID]` handler (where ID is a category id, like `CATEGORY_8`

That should give you what you're after.

If you're using [Commerce Bug](http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net/) (the commercial Magento debugging extension I created and try not to over promote), you can grab this information from the `Layout` tab

[image]